# Prestashop 1.6 - Calling Function from TPL Button

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I have created a button in admin page with the codes below. This is a customised module that I am creating to execute a function from Prestashop back-office.

```
public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params) {
    $shipping = 'index.php?controller=AdminShipping&type=refund&id_order='.$params['id_order'].'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminShipping');
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'shipping'      => $shipping
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/link.tpl');
}
```

The button is displayed with the codes below:

```
<div id="Panel" class="panel">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="icon-money"></i>
    Shipping Charges
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="submitShipLabel" onclick="window.open('{$shipping}','_blank');">Execute</button>
```

My main aim is to execute a function upon button click. I have minimal idea how where to place and call the function from.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

<...If I got it right...>

Add custom handler to url:

```
    $shipping = 'index.php?controller=AdminShipping&type=refund&id_order='.$params['id_order'].'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminShipping').'&customAction=1';
```

Prepend control to your hook:

```
if (Tools::getIsSet('customAction') {
    $this->yourFunction();
}
```

result :

```
public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params) {

    if (Tools::getIsSet('customAction') {
        $this->yourFunction();
    }
    $shipping = 'index.php?controller=AdminShipping&type=refund&id_order='.$params['id_order'].'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminShipping').'&customAction=1';
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'shipping'      => $shipping
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/link.tpl');
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip but unfortunately, the line where prepend takes place broke the page. if (Tools::getIsSet('customAction') {
    $this->yourFunction();
}

Comment: This is probably due to typo errors. 
use Tools::getIsset  instead of Tools::getIsSet

Comment: Yes, I am using Tools::getIsset.

Comment: No, I have tried to play around with it with no success, unfortunately. Tools::getIsset is breaking the page layout.